# manytomany relationship with three tables laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following structure:

```
Action
-id
-name
-type

Routes
-id
-name
-controllers

User
-id
-name
-email
-password
-usergroup_id

Usergroup
-id
-name
-tenant_id
```

I want to make a relationship where I can know what actions on a specific route the user can do, and the same thing for the user group, because if the user does not have the action then the actions of his group will be validated.

In this case would I have to create two pivot tables ?

```
Action_Routes_User
-action_id
-route_id
-user_id

Action_Routes_Usergroup
-action_id
-route_id
-usergroup_id
```

and pass belongsToMany on everything, right?

I managed to make this relationship, but to get what actions X user has in a given route, that gives me a problem:

```
// model User
public function routes()
{
return $this->belongsToMany(Route::class, 'action_route_user', 'user_id', 'route_id');
}

// model Route
public function actionsUser()
{
return $this->belongsToMany(Action::class, 'action_route_user', 'route_id', 'action_id');
}
```

when I do **$user->routes** I get all the routes related to this user, there ok ...

but when I take a route from this collection above for example:

```
$routes = $user->routes;
foreach($routes as $route) {
   $routeActions = $route->actionsUser;

   // here it is getting all actions regardless of user ID
}
```

Example: the user I'm logged in: **Josef**, it takes the routes he has permission **josef->routes**, alright.

But when I take one of this routes: **$route->actionsUser** it's like this is looking for all user actions in pivot table **action_route_user** and not just the user: josef

I believe that a **where user_id** is missing when fetching this pivot table, if so what better way to put it?